Scipy minimization problem - x never changes
I am trying to solve the following problem: I have a sample of stores selected by geography, and I'd like to select 20% of the sample in such a way that the fraction of sales per geography for the selection mimics that of the overall sales distribution by geography.  I tried several iterations of the code below, but for some reason the 'selection' never changes inside the objective function, so test_fraction is always the same and there's no real optimization.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong.  Could someone please help?
Here's my code with sample data:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.special import expit

# Sample data
np.random.seed(0)
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Store': range(1, 101),
    'Geography': np.random.choice(['North', 'South', 'East', 'West'], 100),
    'TotalSales': np.random.rand(100) * 1000
})

# Define the number of stores to select
num_stores = len(data)
target_percentage = 0.2
target_num_stores = int(target_percentage * num_stores)

# Calculate overall sales fraction per geography
overall_sales = data.groupby('Geography')['TotalSales'].sum()
overall_fraction = overall_sales / overall_sales.sum()

# Objective function to minimize squared error and approach target percentage
def objective(selection):
    selection = expit(selection).round()  # Ensure binary selection using sigmoid function

    selected_stores = data.iloc[np.where(selection == 1)]
    
    if len(selected_stores) == 0:
        return np.inf  # Prevent division by zero
    
    test_sales = selected_stores.groupby('Geography')['TotalSales'].sum()
    test_fraction = test_sales / test_sales.sum()
    print(test_fraction)
    print()
    # Calculate the squared error
    error = ((overall_fraction - test_fraction) ** 2).sum()
    
    # Add penalty for deviation from the target number of stores
    penalty = ((np.sum(selection) - target_num_stores) / target_num_stores) ** 2
    
    return error +penalty

# Constraint to select approximately 20% of the stores
def constraint(selection):
    return np.sum(expit(selection).round()) - target_num_stores

# Set up bounds for the decision variables
bounds = [(0, 1) for _ in range(num_stores)]

# Create an initial feasible solution by randomly selecting approximately 20% of the stores
initial_selection = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=num_stores)

# Set up constraints
constraints = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint}

# Solve the optimization problem
result = minimize(objective, initial_selection, bounds=bounds, method='SLSQP', options={'disp': True})

# Solve the optimization problem
result = minimize(objective, x0=initial_selection)#, bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints, method='SLSQP', options={'disp': True})




Because expit([0]) -> np.array([0.5]) and np.array([0.5]).round() -> [1], your "selection" is really processed as a large array of 1s in all instances. Because of this there is no gradient.

Change low in np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=num_stores) to -1?

Thanks @ifly6, but I don't think that's the issue... when I print out 'selection' within the objective function, it's a numpy array of size (100,).  The array does contain 0's and 1's, it's just that the array itself never changes.

I'm not sure about that. That array, after the first line which reassigns and rounds, is entirely populated with 1s. It literally cannot have any 0s in it after rounding https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+logistic+sigmoid. np.allclose(expit(np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=1_000_000)).round(), 1) returns True.

I solved the issue.   Method SLSQP was not right here, but it worked with COBYLA.

Mind adding your solution as a self-answer? It will help future users who have the same problem.

Not sure how?  I think there used to be an 'answer your own question' checkbox, but now I don't see one.

You should have an "Answer your question" button near the bottom of the page. Here's a screenshot of what it looks like for me on one of my questions: https://i.imgur.com/oSZRpuG.png
